# Firebase , Active Directory - Will AD users get created in Firebase as well?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, saml, firebase-admin

I am reading about integrating Azure AD with Firebase so that our corporate customers can use our system using their accounts.
My question is:

When a user with an email a@x.com signs in using AD for the first time, will a User(User with uid, etc) get created in Firebase?

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/1bjydm6/firebase_active_directory_will_ad_users_get/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a new account will be created after a user's first sign in.

Comment: Thank you so much @Robert!

Is there any documentation which I can to show my boss to prove him this?
Still thank you it has solved my question!

Comment: Maybe this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#next_steps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement Firebase Authentication with email and password, please note that the user is created in Firebase Authentication only when you call [create_user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#create_user). So a function that does that might look like this:

```
def create_user(email, password):
    user = auth.create_user(email=email, password=password)
    return user
```

Besides that, please also keep in mind that logging into Firebase happens on the client, and not on the server. So the Firebase Admin SDK doesn't have a method to sign the user in, only the client-side SDKs have such methods.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the answer. But my question was about using Azure AD as an SAML IdP with Firebase. When I add Azure AD as a SAML provider (Not Microsoft login) in Firebase and when a user logs in for the first time, will a User (with uid , email etc) get created in Firebase or not?

Comment: Yes, but the UID is generated on the server as soon as the user signs in for the first time successfully.